# Display this week data in ng-repeat using yyyy/mm/dd format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

Is there a way to limit the display in ng-repeat using date string format? I'm trying to expire a certain data in the table like: if for example the date is `2019/03/22`.. it will not display in the table since it was last week data

```js
angular.module('selectExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.register = {
      regData: {
        branch: {},
      },
      names: [
        {name:"narquois",date:"2019/03/30"},
        {name:"vorpal",date:"2019/03/28"},
        {name:"keen",date:"2019/03/25"},
        {name:"argol",date:"2019/03/18"},
        {name:"long",date:"2019/03/17"},
        {name:"propolis",date:"2019/03/16"}
      ],
    };
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="selectExample" ng-controller="ExampleController">
<table id="example" width="100%">
    <thead>
       <tr align="center">
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Date</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>   
    <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="person in register.names">
         <td align="center">{{ person.name }}</td>
         <td align="center">{{ person.date }}</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table> 
</div>
```

Comment: Use Array#filter() on the array before passing to view

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom filter in which you can get first and last day of week and check date passed from your array is within that range or not.

js

```
$scope.filterCurrentWeek = function(row){   
  var today = new Date(); // get current date
  var first = today.getDate() - today.getDay();
  var last = first + 6;

  var firstDay = new Date(today.setDate(first)).toUTCString();
  console.log(firstDay)
  var lastDay = new Date(today.setDate(last)).toUTCString();
  console.log(lastDay)
  var rowDate = new Date(row.date)
  console.log(rowDate)

  if(Date.parse(firstDay) <= Date.parse(rowDate) && Date.parse(lastDay) >= Date.parse(rowDate)){
    return true;
  }
  else{
    return false;
  }

}
```

html

```
<table id="example" width="100%">
<thead>
   <tr align="center">
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Date</th>
   </tr>
</thead>            
<tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="person in register.names | filter: filterCurrentWeek">
     <td align="center">{{ person.name }}</td>
     <td align="center">{{ person.date }}</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vxv41dkDJBCDivE0i7Du?p=preview)**